# show data in the textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

I want to show my filtered data in the arrays in the textboxes...I’ve been looking in google for days already for the same idea of my program that works but I cant find any help me please.

I think the problem is the script it doesnt work as expected...I need your help guys.

example expected output:

[image]

html:

```
<form name="form" method="get"> 
Search batchcode: <input type="text" id="query" name="search" /><br /> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<td> 
ID: <br /> 
<input id="id1" type="text" name="id1" /> <br /> 
<input id="id2" type="text" name="id2" /> <br /> 
</td> 
<td> 
Name: <br /> 
<input id="name1" type="text" name="name1" /> <br /> 
<input id="name2" type="text" name="name2" /> <br /> 
</td> 
<td> 
Score 1: <br /> 
<input id="optA1" type="text" name="optA1" /> <br /> 
<input id="optA2" type="text" name="optA2" /> <br /> 
</td> 
<td> 
Score 2: <br /> 
<input id="optB1" type="text" name="optB1" /> <br /> 
<input id="optB2" type="text" name="optB2" /> <br /> 
</td> 
<td> 
Other Qualification: <br /> 
<input id="other_qual1" type="text" name="other_qual1" /> <br /> 
<input id="other_qual2" type="text" name="other_qual2" /> <br /> 
</td> 
<td> 
Interview: <br /> 
<input id="interview1" type="text" name="interview1" /> <br /> 
<input id="interview2" type="text" name="interview2" /> <br /> 
</td> 
<td> 
Total: <br /> 
<input id="total1" type="text" name="total1" /> <br /> 
<input id="total2" type="text" name="total2" /> <br /> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</form>
```

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name^=search]').focusout(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url:"search.php",
            type:"GET",
            data: { term : $('#query').val() },
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#id1').val(result.id).show();
                $('#id2').val(result.id).show();
                $('#name1').val(result.name).show();
                $('#name2').val(result.name).show();
                $('#optA1').val(result.score1).show();
                $('#optA2').val(result.score1).show();
                $('#optA1').val(result.score2).show();
                $('#optA2').val(result.score2).show();
                $('#other_qual1').val(result.other_qual).show();
                $('#other_qual2').val(result.other_qual).show();
                $('#interview1').val(result.interview).show();
                $('#interview2').val(result.interview).show();
                $('#total1').val(result.total).show();
                $('#total2').val(result.total).show();
            },
             error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ){
             console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
             console.log(textStatus);
             console.log(errorThrown);
        }

        });
    })
});      
</script>
```

search.php code:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['term'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score WHERE batchcode LIKE '%$q%'");
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$data[] = array('value'=>$row['batchcode'], 
'id' => $row['id'], 
'name' => $row['name'], 
'score1' => $row['score1'], 
'score2' => $row['score2'], 
'other_qual' => $row['other_qual'], 
'interview' => $row['interview'], 
'total' => $row['total']
    );
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

when I go to search.php page I get this output everytime:

[image]

Comment: share code in phpfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test this:

**PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

    $q = $_GET['term'];
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("stackoverflow");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score WHERE batchcode LIKE '%$q%'");

    $data = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $data[] = array(
            'value' => $row['batchcode'],
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'score1' => $row['score1'],
            'score2' => $row['score2'],
            'other_qual' => $row['other_qual'],
            'interview' => $row['interview'],
            'total' => $row['total']
        );
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);

}

?>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send_search_form').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            $(".search_form_input").val('');

         $.ajax({
            url:"search.php",
            type:"GET",
            data: { term : $('#query').val() },
            dataType:"JSON",
            success: function(result) {

            var ii = 1;

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 

                        $('#id'+ii+'').val(result[i].id).show();
                        $('#name'+ii+'').val(result[i].name).show();
                        $('#optA'+ii+'').val(result[i].score1).show();
                        $('#optB'+ii+'').val(result[i].score1).show();
                        $('#other_qual'+ii+'').val(result[i].other_qual).show();
                        $('#interview'+ii+'').val(result[i].interview).show();
                        $('#total'+ii+'').val(result[i].total).show();
                ii++;
                }

            }

        });

    });
});      
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    Search batchcode: <input id="query" name="search" type="text"><br>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID:<br>
            <input id="id1" class="search_form_input" name="id1" type="text"><br>
            <input id="id2" class="search_form_input" name="id2" type="text"><br></td>

            <td>Name:<br>
            <input id="name1" class="search_form_input" name="name1" type="text"><br>
            <input id="name2" class="search_form_input" name="name2" type="text"><br></td>

            <td>Score 1:<br>
            <input id="optA1" class="search_form_input" name="optA1" type="text"><br>
            <input id="optA2" class="search_form_input" name="optA2" type="text"><br></td>

            <td>Score 2:<br>
            <input id="optB1" class="search_form_input" name="optB1" type="text"><br>
            <input id="optB2" class="search_form_input" name="optB2" type="text"><br></td>

            <td>Other Qualification:<br>
            <input id="other_qual1" class="search_form_input" name="other_qual1" type="text"><br>
            <input id="other_qual2" class="search_form_input" name="other_qual2" type=
            "text"><br></td>

            <td>Interview:<br>
            <input id="interview1" class="search_form_input" name="interview1" type="text"><br>
            <input id="interview2" class="search_form_input" name="interview2" type="text"><br></td>

            <td>Total:<br>
            <input id="total1" class="search_form_input" name="total1" type="text"><br>
            <input id="total2" class="search_form_input" name="total2" type="text"><br></td>
        </tr>
    </table><input id="send_search_form" type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: i tried your code still the filtered datas wont show in the textboxes...can you help me?

Comment: i think the javascript is the one doesnt work...can you help me make the javacsript work please.

Comment: the javascript still wont work i think...because it wont show the datas in the textboxes....can you test it in phpfiddle?

Comment: @user3260176 can you confirm that search.php works as it should? Open search.php?term=value and change *value* to something that should get you a result.

Comment: the search.php is working i tried search?term=value it but i think the javascript is the reason the datas wont show in the textboxes.

Comment: @user3260176 do you have a script tag linking to the jQuery library *before* this js-code?

Comment: i want the program to work just like in the example picture above.

Comment: nope...theres no script tag linking to the jquery library

Comment: you need to have somehting like: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` *before* the script you gave us in this question. Wait a few minutes for updated answer, I think I got the problem

Comment: oh i got that link..i thought you where talking about another script function lol sorry.

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the javascsript function.

Comment: @user3260176 what do you get if you just `alert(result)` with the current code?

Comment: nothing happen...i tried to type in the search(textbox) ,refresh it but the script is not working.

Comment: @user3260176 what do you mean with "refresh"?

Comment: it doesnt send data in the search.php page

Comment: @user3260176 you didn't have the correct header in *search.php*. Update the php code to the php in my current code and try again.

Comment: i used your code still the javascript wont send the value i typed in the search(textbox)...in order the search.php work.

Comment: my html code doesnt have button btw just like in the picture above.

Comment: @user3260176 I am going to try this on my xampp, wait a few minutes, please.

Comment: @user3260176 check my updated answer. It works on my localhost.

Comment: does it work and show the datas in the textboxes? y it doesnt work to me?

Comment: Oh sorry. Change mysql_select_db to match your db name. Then it will work.

Comment: it has an error on the script can you help me locate it.

Comment: There should not be any more errors. Jusy change in search.php what table you want to select

Comment: the score2 values wont show and the script got a red error in my dreamweaver..il print scrren it for you to  see w8.

Comment: @user3260176 see edited answer to show score2 values, and about that error: I didn't find any error. As long as the code works and does what it should do, you shouldn't care about that. Oh, and don't forget to upvote if my answer helped you! :)

Comment: thank you dude...Daniel do you still have time?? can you still help me? how do i change the code that if i type wrong bathcode or i typed not stored in the database batchcode...the (textboxes) will be empty?

Comment: @user3260176 Yep: wait a min.

Comment: @user3260176 done. I added `class="search_form_input"` to every textbox, and then, every time the form is submitted, all those textboxes are cleared, then if any result is found, they get filled with that data, otherwise they remain empty. Now don't forget to upvote my answer ;).

Comment: did you edit the html only?? cause i tried it and its not working?

Comment: @user3260176 I also added `$(".search_form_input").val('');` after `event.preventDefault();` in the JavaScript-code.

Comment: last 1 more...ill put a update(button) can you help me make a update function for it? or maybe next time? i tried to vote up your answer but it says i need 15 rep..maybe if i get a 15 rep i vote up ur answer :D

Comment: @user3260176 Post that problem in a new question mate! :)

Comment: Kk :D thank you so much dude for your time and effort...you helped me big time on it :D....il make a update function on it maybe tomorow cause its 2am already here in my place philippines...im sleepy :D cya!